# Correct type for nested array in a recursive function in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, recursion, types

I am trying to implement a function `flattenDeep` which is quite similar to lodash's [`_.flattenDeep(array)`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flattenDeep) in typescript, however i meet some problems with type definitions, here is my code:

```js
export interface DeepArray<T> extends Array<T | DeepArray<T>> {}

export const flattenDeep = <T>(array: DeepArray<T>): T[] => {
  return [].concat(...array.map(arr => {
    if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
      return flattenDeep(arr)
    } else {
      return arr
    }
  }))
}

flattenDeep([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]) // should return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

So far it looks fine, when i test it, the functionality itself is alright, however the `flattenDeep()` function is inferring the wrong return type:

```js
const arr = [1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]
const flattenedArr = flattenDeep(arr)

// inferred type is:
// const flattenedArr: (number | (number | (number | number[])[])[])[]
// but it should expected to be number[] or Array<number>? since the final result is a one dimensional array
```

So how do i resolve this problem for providing correct types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that since `DeepArray<T>` is recursively typed and structurally identical to `(T | DeepArray<T>)[]`, there isn't a unique `T` corresponding to `DeepArray<T>`.  For example, the type `DeepArray<number>` is compatible with `(number | DeepArray<number>)[]` and therefore with `(number | (number | DeepArray<number>)[])[]`, etc.

So when the compiler is trying to interpret a type like `(number | number[])[]` as `DeepArray<T>` for some `T`, it isn't guaranteed to infer `number`.  It is perfectly free to pick `number | number[]`, or `number | (number | number[])[]`, or all sorts of things as long as whatever it chooses for `T` allows `(number | number[])[]` to be compatible with `DeepArray<T>`.  So you can't count on inference to "flatten" `T` even though the implementation of `flattenDeep()` does flatten the value:

```
declare const flattenDeepOrig: <T>(array: DeepArray<T>) => T[]
const oops = flattenDeepOrig([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]) 
// const oops: (number | (number | (number | number[])[])[])[]
```

You could, of course, manually specify the desired value of `T` and the compiler would be able to check that it works, and generate an error if not:

```
const okayAnnotated = flattenDeepOrig<number>([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]) // number[]
```

But presumably you want the compiler to figure it out for you.  To do so it's much better to have a type like `<T>(array: T[])=>FlattenArray<T>[]` for some appropriate `FlattenArray<T>` definition that *explicitly* collapses deeply nested array types to a flat type.  That's because given a value `[1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]` as `T[]`, the only reasonable inference candidate for `T` is something like `number | (number | (number | number[])[])[]`, at which point you want `FlattenArray<T>` to flatten it *explicitly* to `number`.  So we just need to define `FlattenArray<>`.

---

Unfortunately, the straightforward definition of `FlattenArray<T>` would be circular in a way that the compiler does not support:

```
type FlattenArrayOops<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FlattenArrayOops<T[number]> : T; // error!
//   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  <-- Type alias 'FlattenArrayOops' circularly references itself.
```

There is an open suggestion, [microsoft/TypeScript#26980](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980), to allow such circular types, but for now there's no officially supported way to get this behavior.

In cases like this what I usually do is approximate a circular type by manually "unrolling" the definition into a version that works up to some fixed depth, like this:

```
type FlattenArray<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA0<T[number]> : T;
type FA0<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA1<T[number]> : T;
type FA1<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA2<T[number]> : T;
type FA2<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA3<T[number]> : T;
type FA3<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA4<T[number]> : T;
type FA4<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA5<T[number]> : T;
type FA5<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA6<T[number]> : T;
type FA6<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA7<T[number]> : T;
type FA7<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FA8<T[number]> : T;
type FA8<T> = T extends Array<any> ? FAX<T[number]> : T;
type FAX<T> = T; // bail out
```

Here you can see that `FlattenArray<T>` is not defined in terms of itself, but in terms of a similar type `FA0<T>`, which is defined in terms of a similar type `FA1<T>`, etc., until it reaches depth `FAX<T>` and just bails out.  As long as your use cases tend not to be incredibly deeply nested, it should work for you:

```
declare const flattenDeep: <T>(array: T[]) => FlattenArray<T>[];
const okay = flattenDeep([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]) // number[]
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEWGDAEEopMBPAHgBUA+OUVJAEwGc4yKba4AfAkVLkqdeowDecAL4BYAFCLsEJO3gAvAFxDi3MUgCuAWwBGaAXCNm0AbQC6jALxXDAGzcBCOJk4AKa3MoS0C7ewBKB0VFdDdMGBZCYgB5KAQAc2oAkyDLbJtgwVCoB0iI+myPb184fNyinLCy8OiFVmBsOKg8FTV4WPjE4VSMnXE-TFFKHSSRHnFwuCdGWiilBV71OAgIME4XAYTgJFmR9L9bAEYAGjhbACZb2wBmJ4AWe3tbgFZPxYB6f61Yp5EGCOoWBoFUowiJrTbwCAAayoJCQSAgMHiwFYSzghyGKTSmWKFSuT0ed1edw+XzgvwicEBrmh9laMEoYDwADE4kckPpKMlduxxHi+MxjhwuFNqJgkJRGAB+OC8wbHQXCvZ0WzFRxwHS0ADcTKBaCg0E8imZcDgAD8HY6nc67bbqABad1wWicvCYNwIGoAcjV-M1IqDcGwCCg2HckzclDg3XQaGOuE4CBg7GAbnQADp2b7VXyWIKxS4JSAWNLy-LFXAVdySAAGHV6xiGo2KDlc1WtivepjVqWcOsK5X9y7txpQfVdnvF5vThji4c1sey+uT5v3GcFefe7sKXs8kh71eV9ejmXzbeN-vPfdBQ-Gxd95tPy9DyVsTd3icH2bN5nzQV9j1PfsQO-KsN1vMR7ybEhvlAudOyPd8zxQmDrz-eCaEQ-sADZUPAzDiMHWCb3HBskIAdlI9C3xPJcSAYnDf1rLdAKQgAORiDQwliPxIfiOJHPCaJ3EgAA0BIXYSzzkmCTWZUxMAQNxtkMGBWnaTpJh6VQtgJY5ZjGBgJimQ1SiWRhQzLWUGAcY8EW2FEkwOUszOEC4bjuSkXneT4fj+U0WSCNZWjgIA)